# Test the number of activerecord queries in ruby unit test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, activerecord

Is there a way to test for the number of mysql queries made by a specific function ? Just want to keep a check on the query limit, as a minor change in the function would trigger 1000 queries in place of just one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [assert_queries](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActiveRecord/TestCase/assert_queries) method. See how to use it [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/19fa8fa3c436ed5b25e7ed0005f128487a7d1f0b/activerecord/test/cases/batches_test.rb#L15):

```
def test_each_should_excecute_one_query_per_batch
  assert_queries(Post.count + 1) do
    Post.find_each(:batch_size => 1) do |post|
      assert_kind_of Post, post
    end
  end
end
```